My laravel app built with tailwind and vue will not load correctly
I have a laravel app build with tailwaind css and Vue
I have run npm build already. but css would not load what should be the issue?
This is on ubuntu vps
I ran npm run build already
I am using vite also
I am runing this on ubuntu vps
enter image description here

Look at the browser's Developer Console, are there any messages there? Any red lines in the Network tab? We cannot tell you what's wrong with that little information.

GET
http://206.81.17.232/public/installer/css/style.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 418ms]GET
http://206.81.17.232/public/installer/img/ps-logo.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 846ms]
this is what I see in the log

I don't think public should be in those links. In fact, if I take them out, the page shows up. You'll have to fix your links

I cant find that within the code could the problem come from this .htaccess file 
RewriteEngine On
Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
Rewrite to public directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]


It wouldn't have anything to do with your htaccess. It's in the template that creates <link href="/public/installer/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>. You don't show any code, so couldn't tell you how to fix it

I couldnt seem to find  anyway i have code. I also wouldnt know what part of the code would be important in this situation

It would be in one of the template files, most likely somewhere in /resources.

the links in the code seem to be fine could this maybe have something to do with apache on my vps

No, I highly doubt it. This is a code issue where it's using public when it shouldn't be. Apache wouldn't cause that. You'll need to figure out why.

I have noticed that the ASSET_URL=Public adds the 'public' part from  .env

You shouldn't have public in the ASSET_URL, since your Apache config already has the webroot to be public.

Loading module from “https://example.com/www.https://www.example.com/build/assets/PsObject.a17ef38f.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).  I have fixed assets issue however www. gets added to even the .env automatically  above is a network log
